# Cannot run Firefox (geckodriver) properly from PyCharm python console

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

So i use PyCharm 2018.2.3, geckodriver 0.20, Firefox 63.0 and Python 3.6.5 in it for my Selenium auto-tests.

What I try to do in Python Console to run the driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
```

So the geckodriver runs in a new window. Then I ususally write

```
url = "https://website-address.com/"
wd.get(url)
```

But this time I get the message:

> ```
> Previous command is still running. Please wait or press Ctrl+C in console to interrupt.
> ```

And then in like a couple of minutes geckodriver exit with these messages in log:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
>     keep_alive=True)
>   File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
>     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>   File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>   File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>   File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
> ```

Please help me to understand what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and was fixed after I update the geckodriver to v0.21.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated the geckodriver to v0.21.0 and got the error: `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` which made me to downgrade the driver like a month and a bit ago. I also tried v.0.19.1, v.0.20.0 and gor the same error as I mentioned in the question. (Plus I upgraded Selenium to v.3.14 just to be sure that everything is up-to-date).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, seems to be an issue with your firewall, check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/212feb8f-cf96-4561-9953-40a21d21ea47/exception-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine?forum=netfxnetcom . I'm running my tests on linux so i don't see any similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I've opened an issue on geckodriver github (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1369), which was closed by a developer and I got an actual answer here in another similar issue: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1305 - they've released a new version of geckodriver which fixed everything.

P.S. I'm almost absolutely sure I had no issues with my firewall.